# Criar um algoritmo que salva os dados em HD

Tags: c++, arquivo

Criei uma agenda simples para gravar contatos de um usuário, porém o professor pediu para que os dados agora sejam salvos em HD para preservar os contatos mesmo após desligar o computador.

Eu tenho que escrever todo o código usando as propriedades de arquivo que estou procurando na internet, ou posso apenas implementar a funcionalidade no código já pronto?

Segue o código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
void incluir();
void alterar(); 
void excluir();
void recuperar();
void exibir();
int vet[10]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
struct agenda {
    string email;
    string nome;
    string telefone;
};
struct agenda pessoa[10];
int main () {
    int opc;    
    do{
        cout<<"[1] incluir contato"<<endl;
        cout<<"[2] Alterar contato"<<endl;
        cout<<"[3] Excluir contato"<<endl;
        cout<<"[4] Recuperar contato"<<endl;
        cout<<"[5] Exibir contato"<<endl;
        cout<<"[6] Sair"<<endl;
        cin>>opc;
        system("clear || cls");
        switch (opc){
            case 1:
                incluir();

            break;

            case 2:
                alterar();

            break;  

            case 3:
                excluir();

            break;

            case 4:
                recuperar();

            break;

            case 5:
                exibir();

            break;

            case 6:
            break;

            default:
                cout<<"Opção Invalida"<<endl;   
        }
    }while(opc != 6);

    return 0;
}

void incluir(){ 
    int i, cont=0;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        if(vet[i] == 0){
            cout<<"Digite o Email"<<endl;
            cin.ignore();
            cin>>pessoa[i].email;
            cout<<"Digite o Nome"<<endl;
            cin.ignore();
            getline(cin, pessoa[i].nome);
            cout<<"Digite o Telefone"<<endl;
            cin.ignore();
            cin>>pessoa[i].telefone;
            vet[i]=1;
            system("clear || cls");
            break;

        }
        else{
            cont++;
        }

    }
        if(cont==10){
            cout<<"Agenda Cheia"<<endl;
        }

}


void alterar(){
    int i, escolha, cont2=0, escolha2;
    cout<<"Qual Contato Deseja Alterar?"<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        if(vet[i] == 0){
            cout<<"["<<i+1<<"] Vazio"<<endl;
        }
        else{
            cout<<"["<<i+1<<"] "<<pessoa[i].nome<<endl;
        }
    }
    do{
        cin>>escolha;
        if((escolha<=10) && (escolha>0)){
            if(vet[escolha-1] == 1){
                system("clear || cls");
                cout<<"Qual dado deseja alterar?"<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<"[1] Email"<<endl;
                cout<<"[2] Nome"<<endl;
                cout<<"[3] Telefone"<<endl;
                cin>>escolha2;
                if(escolha2 == 1){
                    system("clear || cls");
                    cout<<"Digite o Email"<<endl;
                    cin.ignore();
                    cin>>pessoa[escolha-1].email;
                    system("clear || cls");
                }
                else if (escolha2 == 2){
                    system("clear || cls");
                    cout<<"Digite o Nome"<<endl;
                    cin.ignore();
                    getline(cin, pessoa[escolha-1].nome);
                    system("clear || cls");
                }
                else if(escolha2==3){
                    system("clear || cls");
                    cout<<"Digite o Telefone"<<endl;
                    cin.ignore();
                    cin>>pessoa[escolha-1].telefone;
                    system("clear || cls");
                }
                cont2=1;
            }
            else{
                cout<<"Contato Vazio"<<endl;
            } 



        }

        else{
            cout<<"Contato não existente"<<endl;
        }
    }while(cont2!=1);
}

void excluir(){
    int i, escolha, cont2=0;
    system("clear || cls");
    cout<<"Qual Contato Deseja Excluir?"<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        if(vet[i] == 0){
            cout<<"["<<i+1<<"] Vazio"<<endl;
        }
        else{
            cout<<"["<<i+1<<"] "<<pessoa[i].nome<<endl;
        }
    }
    do{
        cin>>escolha;
        if((escolha<=10) && (escolha>0)){
            vet[escolha-1]=0;
            system("clear || cls");
            cont2=1;
        }
        else{
            cout<<"Contato Inexistente"<<endl;
        }
    }while(cont2!=1);
}

void recuperar(){
    int i, escolha, cont2=0;
    system("clear || cls");
    cout<<"Atenção: Você so pode recuperar um usuário, se nao houver armazenado outra pessoa no mesmo campo após a exclusão."<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Qual campo deseja recuperar?"<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        if(vet[i] == 0){
            cout<<"["<<i+1<<"] Vazio"<<endl;
        }
        else{
            cout<<"["<<i+1<<"] "<<pessoa[i].nome<<endl;
        }
    }
    do{
        cin>>escolha;
        if((escolha<=10) && (escolha>0)){
            vet[escolha-1]=1;
            system("clear || cls");
            cont2=1;
        }
        else{
            cout<<"Contato Inexistente"<<endl;
        }
    }while(cont2!=1);
}

void exibir(){
    int i, escolha, cont2=0, escolha2=0;
    system("clear || cls");
    cout<<"Qual Contato Deseja Exibir?"<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        if(vet[i] == 0){
            cout<<"["<<i+1<<"] Vazio"<<endl;
        }
        else{
            cout<<"["<<i+1<<"] "<<pessoa[i].nome<<endl;
        }
    }
    do{
        cin>>escolha;
        if((escolha<=10) && (escolha>0)){
            system("clear || cls");
            cout<<"Nome: "<<pessoa[escolha-1].nome<<endl;
            cout<<"Email: "<<pessoa[escolha-1].email<<endl;
            cout<<"Telefone: "<<pessoa[escolha-1].telefone<<endl;
            cout<<endl;
            cout<<"[1] Sair"<<endl; 
            do{
                cin>>escolha2;
                if(escolha2==1){
                    cont2=1;
                    system("clear || cls");
                }
                else{
                    cout<<"Opção Invalida"<<endl;
                }
            }while(escolha2!=1);
        }
        else{
            cout<<"Contato Inexistente"<<endl;
        }
    }while(cont2!=1);
}
```

Comment: Não temos como saber do que se trata: "as propriedades de arquivo que estou procurando na internet"

Comment: O professor apenas passou o trabalho e nao explicou nada sobre arquivo, as propriedades de arquivo que me refiro e pegar os dados, telefone, nome e email que o usuario for inserindo e salvar elas em HD para quando abrir novamente os dados continuarem la. Eu posso fazer isso em cima do codigo ja escrito ou devo reescrever toda a agenda novamente?

Comment: Você pode votar em tudo também, veja o [tour].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, é possível, porém não quer dizer que seja o mais organizado. Se o intuito é só resolver o problema, dá para inserir neste código, se quer fazer o certo, a manipulação seria completamente separada e as partes apenas se comunicariam, cada um com sua responsabilidade.

Tem várias coisas que poderiam ser mais organizadas ou até mesmo otimizadas (nem é sobre velocidade, é o código mesmo). E poderia ser mais C++, este código na verdade é essencialmente C, exceto pelos *streams*.

Justamente por ter algumas coisas ruins será um pouco mais difícil integrar a manipulação do arquivo, seja junto ou separado. A lógica usada funciona de forma muito específica. Não é que vai ter que fazer tudo de novo, mas vários pontos terão que ser mudados.

Tem outra questão, o requisito é só gravar ou manipular todos os dados no arquivo? Se for só gravar fica muito mais fácil porque pode manter a lógica, mesmo ela sendo ruim, e criar apenas rotinas que gravam e leem os dados do arquivo e jogam na memória, aí o grosso do seu código nem precisa saber que existe algo do arquivo. Pode colocar opção para ler e gravar ou pode deixar automático, ou seja, lê tudo e joga no *array* quando inicia e toda vez que mexer no *array* grava tudo de novo no arquivo. Isto é ineficiente e pode trazer problemas em grande escala, mas para um exercício pode ser uma alternativa já que não vai manipular milhões de dados.

Só não ache que tudo isto sempre será assim, esta é uma forma extremamente simplificada, em códigos reais, muita coisa precisa ser diferente.

[Documentação](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/fstream).